# Incorrect regex for numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches only 10, 11 and 12 numbers. I tried this:

```
\b[10|11|12]{1}\b
```

But no matches found here. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
\b(10|11|12)\b
```

Check it at work [here](http://regex101.com/r/gV8nL5)

Also, no need to specify `{1}`, it is implicit.

[Square brackets](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) are used to match a character from a set

> Match anything inside the square brackets for ONE character position
>   once and only once, for example, [12] means match the target to 1 and
>   if that does not match then match the target to 2 while [0123456789]
>   means match to any character in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: You probably want to make this a non-capturing group if you are not going to use the result: \b(?:10|11|12)\b

Comment: `\b1[0-2]\b` is equivalent (I hope!) and shorter, but is it more understandable? (BTW, regex101.com is cool, thanks!)

Comment: @xenon: you are right. In this case, for me it would just lower readability. If you are not going to use the result - then does not matter if it is capturing or not :)

Comment: thanks! always used http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, but regex101 is way better :)